# Why the parameter being passed to the controller method from jquery is null even it's not?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

I have been trying to call my .cs method in the controller from jquery json and it gets called but the parameter passed is always null. Why? Even i checked in the console log and it shows the value being passed but somehow it doesn't get passed to the method. It's null.

```
 $('#AppointmentDate').change(function () {

                var AppointmentDate = '2018-04-30'; //document.getElementById('AppointmentDate').value;

                $.ajax
                ({
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetTimeSlotsByDate", "Appointment")',
                    type: 'GET',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset= utf-8",
                    data: JSON.stringify(AppointmentDate),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (results) {

                        $("#fk_TimeSlotID").html(""); // clear before appending new list 

                        $.each(results, function (i, slot) {
                            $("#fk_TimeSlotID").append(
                                $('<option></option>').val(slot.TimeSlotID).html(slot.FromTo));
                        });

                        console.log('Time slots returned');
                        console.log(AppointmentDate);

                    }
                });
```

Method:

```
 public ActionResult GetTimeSlotsByDate(DateTime? RequestedAppointmentDate)
        {
            TimeSlotsRepository TimeSlotsRep = new TimeSlotsRepository();
            List<TimeSlotsModel> ListTimeSlotsModel = TimeSlotsRepository.getTimeSlotsByDate(RequestedAppointmentDate);

            return Json(ListTimeSlotsModel, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

This is the rendered URL

```
http://localhost:13924/Appointment/GetTimeSlotsByDate?"2018-04-30"
```

Comment: `data: { RequestedAppointmentDate: AppointmentDate }` and delete the pointless `contentType: "application/json; charset= utf-8",` (a GET has no body)

Comment: @StephenMuecke: I did but still it doesn't work. Same problem

Comment: It does work (and it will generate the correct url with `..../GetTimeSlotsByDate?RequestedAppointmentDate=2018-04-30`

Comment: If you're using the code you've provided (hardcoded date string) *and* changed to `data: { RequestedAppointmentDate ...` then it should work.  If you're using `$("AppointmentDate").val()` then it's likely *that* val is not in the correct format, so it's not recognised as a date (eg could be in `dd/mm/yyyy`) format while .Net would be expecting `mm-dd-yyyy` format).

Comment: Can you provide the *actual* URL that's being generated?  (from the browser network tag)

Comment: Yup, this is a date format issue between JS and ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: @IanKemp, OP is sending the date in iso format so it will always bind correctly

Comment: @Stacky I know its not ideal but what happens if you try pass the date back as a string? Just to see what happens

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your data to query string parameters and pass to server in
 url as

```
somesite.com/Appointment/GetTimeSlotsByDate?RequestedAppointmentDate=your date
```

Comment: define date parameter in controller as string and then you can parse your string to datetime

Answer (score 0):

try this ,Its working for me

```
 $('#AppointmentDate').change(function () {

           // var AppointmentDate = '2018-04-30'; //document.getElementById('AppointmentDate').value;

            $.ajax
            ({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetTimeSlotsByDate", "Appointment")',
                type: 'GET',
                contentType: "application/json; charset= utf-8",
                //data: JSON.stringify(AppointmentDate),
                data: { RequestedAppointmentDate: "2018-04-30" },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (results) {

                    $("#fk_TimeSlotID").html(""); // clear before appending new list 

                    $.each(results, function (i, slot) {
                        $("#fk_TimeSlotID").append(
                            $('<option></option>').val(slot.TimeSlotID).html(slot.FromTo));
                    });

                    console.log('Time slots returned');
                    console.log(AppointmentDate);

                }
            });
```